# OpenGL mouse listener return

Tags: opengl, haskell, mouse

I'm trying to use the mouse listener in Haskell using OpenGL and have run into a problem. Apparently the return given for the x and y coordinates is a GLint. The problem is in then using these because I need a GLfloat. Simple parsing doesn't appear to fix the problem. On a more technical note, why would this return an int at all when the entire size of the screen is represented in OpenGL as only 1 square unit?

Comment: OpenGL has no concept of "mice".

Answer (score 3):

GLUT or GLFW, which are the toolkits that you're probably using to access OpenGL, manage windows for you. They have no idea about what the current view port looks like -- heck, you could even be rendering to only a quarter of the window; that'd mess up your coordinates pretty badly if GLUT/GLFW cared about OpenGL coordinates! Luckily, they do not; the `x` and `y` coordinates that you're getting are actual pixel coordinates on the window, and I think that `(0, 0)` even is in the top left, with the Y axis going downwards. The mouse coordinates are completely separate from OpenGL.

Nonetheless, you can convert a `GLint` into a `GLfloat` using `fromIntegral`.